# DRF: AttributeError: type object 'Plan' has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

I an creating a rest API where I want to have a url with a query parameter like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/API/prices?portion=small
```

To do this I am folliwing the [official docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-query-parameters): "Filtering against query Parameter"

This is my view:

```
class PurchaseList(generics.ListAPIView):
serializer_class = PurchaseSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):

        queryset = Purchase.objects.all()
        portion = self.request.query_params.get('portion', None)

        if portion is not None:
            if portion == "small":
                queryset = queryset.filter(portion=False)
            elif portion == "large":
                queryset = queryset.filter(portion=True)
        return queryset
```

In my urls.py I am creating a router and registering  this view like below:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'prices', views.PurchaseList, base_name='subprices')

urlpatterns = [
    path('API/', include(router.urls)),
...
]
```

However, this is producing the below error on `runserver`:

```
AttributeError: type object 'PurchaseList' has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'
```

I have already managed to make the api work without any query following their [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/) again. How can I solve this. im certinely doing something wrong either in the `router.register()` or in the `view`

Comment: What is `if username is not None:` doing here?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem that is my mistake. it should say `if portion is not None:`

Comment: just confirmed, the duplicate solved my question. Strange how sometimes SO questions do not appear in google search.

Comment: you can search stack overflow after google to see these results